# Does this function have inflection points?

Tags: calculus

Does the function $f(x) = 3$ have inflection points?
$f''(x) = f'(x) = 0$ so it seems like every $x$ is an inflection point but according to the graph there is none... What is the correct answer?

Comment: Since _all_ of the derivatives of a constant function are zero, it doesn't have "concavity", so the idea of inflection points isn't really applicable...

Comment: This was a true or false question in my exam and I want to know if I was right... What is the official answer?

Comment: It would be false.

Comment: Since an inflection point indicates where the concavity of the curve represented by the function changes, I would think that there are no inflection points, rather than that every point is an inflection point.

Comment: What is the exact definition of inflection point you use?

Comment: This was a true or false question: "if $f''(x) = f'(x) = 0$ then $f$ has inflection points". I answered "false" and gave this as a counter example... There must be an official definition that determines whether I was right or wrong

Comment: If this appeared on an exam, then I expect that your professor has given you some definition of inflection point which would determine whether $f(x)=3$ has inflection points. Most terms in mathematics don't have "official definitions", since the details can vary from person to person.

Answer (score 0):

An inflection point is a point where the sign of curvature changes from negative to positive, or vice versa. More precisely, $x$ is an inflection point of a twice differentiable function $f$ if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f''(y)<0$ for all $y\in (x-\varepsilon,x)$ and $f''(y)>0$ for all $x\in (x,x+\varepsilon)$, or if $f''(y)>0$ for all $y\in (x-\varepsilon,x)$ and $f''(y)<0$ for all $x\in (x,x+\varepsilon)$. Since $f''(x)=0$ for all $x$ when $f(x)\equiv 3$, no point fits the above definition, so we conclude that no points are inflection points. See [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html) for more information.